# Running curl on windows

Tags: windows, curl, windows64

I'm trying to install curl from the following link

https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

from Windows 64 - Generic. But the zip folder doesn't have curl.exe file. I don't know what to do. How do I run curl in my cmd?

Comment: download the version under the **Win64 - MinGW64** block way down at the bottom... you need to unzip with [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).  **cd** to the directory where you unzipped curl and you should be good to go.

Comment: I think this post aswear this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845021/running-curl-on-windows/67385757#67385757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded this one: 
Win64 x86_64 7zip   7.49.1  binary  SSL     SSH     Viktor Szakáts  1.81 MB

and the zip folder contains a curl.exe (within the bin folder).

Go to this directory with cmd and just enter curl --help or any other curl command.

Comment: I don't know what to do with a 7zip file! Can't I have a simple zip.

Comment: The curl.exe still doesn't run. It tries to open when I click on it and closes right then.